# g++: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5pluma13Plxxxx

Tags: c++, c, windows, c++11, gcc

I want to compile project "pluma".I use mingw，and open this project with codeblock with default cbp.
The first two project go well, with following log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -Wall -DPLUMA_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\include -I..\..\src -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\src\Pluma\Dir.cpp -o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Dir.o
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -Wall -DPLUMA_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\include -I..\..\src -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\src\Pluma\DLibrary.cpp -o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\DLibrary.o
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -Wall -DPLUMA_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\include -I..\..\src -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\src\Pluma\Host.cpp -o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Host.o
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -Wall -DPLUMA_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\include -I..\..\src -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\src\Pluma\PluginManager.cpp -o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\PluginManager.o
mingw32-g++.exe -std=c++0x -Wall -DPLUMA_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\include -I..\..\src -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\src\Pluma\Provider.cpp -o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Provider.o
mingw32-g++.exe -shared  -Wl,--out-implib=..\..\lib\libpluma-d.a -Wl,--dll  ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Dir.o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\DLibrary.o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Host.o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\PluginManager.o ..\..\ztemp\mingw\debug\src\Pluma\Provider.o  -o ..\..\lib\pluma-d.dll  
Output file is ..\..\lib\pluma-d.dll with size 1.36 MB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -DPLUGIN_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\src\interface -I..\..\src\plugin -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\interface\Warrior.cpp -o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\elite-warriors\debug\src\interface\Warrior.o
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -DPLUGIN_EXPORTS -g -O0 -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\src\interface -I..\..\src\plugin -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\plugin\Connector.cpp -o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\elite-warriors\debug\src\plugin\Connector.o
mingw32-g++.exe -shared   -Wl,--dll -L..\..\..\lib ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\elite-warriors\debug\src\interface\Warrior.o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\elite-warriors\debug\src\plugin\Connector.o  -o ..\..\bin\plugins\elite-warriors-d.dll -lpluma-d  
Output file is ..\..\bin\plugins\elite-warriors-d.dll with size 269.04 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
0 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

But when I compile the third project and link with the lib generated before.I get following log:

```
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -O0 -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\src\interface -I..\..\src\host -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\host\Main.cpp -o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\host\Main.o
mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -g -O0 -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\src\interface -I..\..\src\host -c F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\interface\Warrior.cpp -o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\interface\Warrior.o
mingw32-g++.exe -L..\..\..\lib -L..\..\..\lib -o ..\..\bin\aztecs-d.exe ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\host\Main.o ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\interface\Warrior.o  -lpluma-d  
F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\host\Main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\src\host\Main.cpp:30:16: warning: deleting object of abstract class type 'Warrior' which has non-virtual destructor will cause undefined behavior [-Wdelete-non-virtual-dtor]
   30 |         delete warrior;
      |                ^~~~~~~
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\host\Main.o: in function `main':
F:/workspace/mec/Pluma-1.1/example/src/host/Main.cpp:15: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5pluma13PluginManager14loadFromFolderERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\host\Main.o: in function `ZN5pluma5Pluma18acceptProviderTypeI15WarriorProviderEEvv':
F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\build\mingw/../../../include/Pluma/Pluma.inl:35: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN5pluma13PluginManager12registerTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjj'
d:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: ..\..\..\ztemp\mingw\aztec-warfare\debug\src\host\Main.o: in function `ZN5pluma5Pluma12getProvidersI15WarriorProviderEEvRSt6vectorIPT_SaIS5_EE':
F:\workspace\mec\Pluma-1.1\example\build\mingw/../../../include/Pluma/Pluma.inl:46: undefined reference to `_imp___ZNK5pluma13PluginManager12getProvidersERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

However,I use "nm libpluma-d.a" to check out the symbols，I see:

```
00000000 I __imp___ZN5pluma13PluginManager14loadFromFolderERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEb
00000000 I __imp___ZN5pluma13PluginManager12registerTypeERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjj
00000000 I __imp___ZNK5pluma13PluginManager12getProvidersERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE
```

These symbols are existed, but only they are prefixed with "__imp".There is another "_" in the prefix.Is this the problem?How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to use the same standard revision for all of them (preferably all the same compiler flags too), the messages about missing string functions are because pre-C++11 string is different to C++11 string which you requested in the first part but not the second

Answer (score -1):

I know what's go wrong.In the lib dir，there is other libs named "libpluma.dll.a, libpluma-d.dll.a,pluma.dll" which is attached with project. Maybe mingw-g++ uses libpluma-d.dll.a，as result linker goes wrong. When I delete these libs，I make it.

Comment: That's merely trying things, at random, until something appears to work. A solution needs to describe the core issue. This requires that the author understood the issue.